# How can I temporarily type a text with different font that defined in the style file?

Tags: fonts

For example, I've written a text, and in the somewhere of there I wanna use different font size, font type, color etc. Or in another way, hown can I change my font temporarily within the text ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I use a particular font for a small section of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've edited to correct problem with simple solution.  Here's how I generally do it if the quantity of text is small enough to be done inline:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\finline[3][]{\begin{myfont}[#1]{#2}#3\end{myfont}}%

% ENVIRONMENT FOR NEW FONT
\newenvironment{myfont}[2][]{\csname#2\endcsname[#1]}{}

\newcommand{\Alpine}[1][]{\fontfamily{Alpine}#1\selectfont}

\begin{document}

Original Font \finline[\fontsize{30}{36}]{Alpine}{Text in New Font}
returned to original font
\end{document}
```

Sorry I can't on this old-old computer turn my PDF into a jpg to show you.  Will edit when I can.  Obviously Alpine is a font installed on my computer.  You will have to pick a font that is on your computer

Comment: Thank you for this example.  I was able to use it combined with another one to solve my issue regarding the tufte-book class and using Vietnamese:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631157/th%c3%adch-nh%e1%ba%a5t-h%e1%ba%a1nh-in-latex-tufte-book-class/632133#632133