# Name (code) of fonts in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I would like to know the name (code) of fonts in `(La)TeX`. Let me explain myself:

When I want to import a symbol from a different font, I type something like

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {cmsy}{}
```

Here cmsy is the `(La)TeX` encoding, `(La)TeX` name, `(La)TeX` code or whatever you want for the family `Computer Modern` (which is set by default in `LaTeX`).

If I want to import a symbol from the `mathabx`package (in this case `subset`symbol) I can write

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
```

Now the code is `matha`.

My question is:

> > Suppose I want to import a single character from Century Modern TT font. What code has it in `(La)TeX`? Which is the equivalent for `cmsy` and `matha` in any other font?

Comment: Such family names only exist if the font has been prepared for latex. The author of packages like mathabx choose them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I suppose this is not the case. Then, there exists a way to be able to define math symbols in such a font?

Comment: There are several questions like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/berry-naming-scheme-list-of-latex-font-families https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100575/how-can-i-temporarily-type-a-text-with-different-font-that-defined-in-the-style